# I've tried to do a loop in ggplot saving the results to a list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to loop ggplot to save them to a list. I have a problem since all the graphs appear to me with the data of the last variable. Can you help me please?
I would like to have the graphics stored in a list

this is what my data looks like:

```
head(rev_regions1m)
         World           US      Eurozone Emerging.Markets Asia.Pacific.Ex.Japon       date
1 -0.015025440 -0.004314109 -0.0074216799     -0.016600603          -0.020172773 2018-12-31
2 -0.015025440 -0.004314109 -0.0074216799     -0.016600603          -0.020172773 2019-01-01
3 -0.015025440 -0.004314109 -0.0074216799     -0.016600603          -0.020172773 2019-01-02
4  0.016668433  0.001509360 -0.0007849854     -0.003445408          -0.007896815 2019-01-03
5  0.016668433  0.001509360 -0.0007849854     -0.003445408          -0.007896815 2019-01-04
6 -0.009066019 -0.005461343 -0.0051865009     -0.013999017          -0.016930263 2019-01-07
>
```

this is the code i have:

```
plot<-list()
for (i in 1:(length(rev_regions1m)-1)) {
  plot[[i]]<-ggplot(rev_regions1m)+
    geom_line((aes(x=date, y= rev_regions1m[,i])),size=1.4, color="midnightblue", inherit.aes = FALSE)+
    labs(x="Date", y="Value", title = "Revisions 1M", subtitle = names_regions[i])+
    theme_wsj()+ 
    scale_colour_wsj("colors6")
}
```

Could anyone help me, please!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow :) In order for us to help you, please provide a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example. For example, to produce a minimal data set, you can use `head()`, `subset()`. **Then use `dput()`** to give us something that can be put in R immediately. Alternatively, you can use base R datasets such as `mtcars`, `iris`, *etc*.

Comment: try replacing `aes(x=date, y= rev_regions1m[,i])` with `aes_string("date", names(rev_regions1m)[i])`

Comment: thank you very much, it already worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution to produce a list of ggplot objects. The workflow is the following:

1. Split your data to get a list of dataframes adequate to make plots
2. Create you custom plotting function
3. Use `lapply()` to loop over your list of dataframes and create a list of ggplot objects.

> ```
> library(ggplot2)
> # using base R dataset iris
> # Lets say you want to make a plot for each specie and save it into a list
> # split your initial data into pieces that will be used to make plots
> iris_list = split(iris, iris$Species) 
> # create a custom function that take as input a piece of your data
> plot_fun = function(irisdf) {
>   ggplot(irisdf, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
>     geom_point()
> }
> # use lapply() on the list of pieces to get a list of ggplot objects
> plots_list = lapply(iris_list, FUN = plot_fun)
> ```